# mPDF - remove image borders

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) to generate PDFs with images.

The problem is, when i render the image, it has a slight border around it.

Is there a way to remove this?

Thanks

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$content = '<img src="/image.png" style="width:100%;border:0;" />';
$mpdf->writeHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output('test.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Please, provide the code.

Comment: instead of border:0; make it as border:none; this may work

Comment: The border style hasn't changed anything. There is a still a very faint grey border.

Comment: Did you ever find an fix for this problem as we get the faint borders too?..

Comment: Looks like a bug in Firefox as Chrome renders the PDF perfectly.

Comment: I have a similar problem - 7 years later.  Transparent pngs have faint borders where the transparent areas start.  No borders when rendered on HTML page, or in image editors - only in mPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mean to necro post but this is the first and only thing popping on Google.

Convert your image to CMYK.  That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and should use Imagick. I did two things:

1. added a white border like this

`$signature = new \Imagick(); $signature->borderImage('white',1,1);`

2. instead of adding `<img src="...">` I created a `div` and added it as background using css.

that worked.